# Highlight words in a cell (not the cell) by matching WHOLE WORDS only?

Tags: excel, vba, text, compare, highlight

I am trying to make code for an excel document that will allow me to accomplish the following:

- Search a worksheet for a listed set of words (as defined by the name manager)
- Search for the listed words as whole words only, while taking into account, case sensitivity, words that are preceded/followed by punctuation, etc.
- Format the listed words within their cells (not the cell itself) to a new font color (ideally I would like it to be highlighted, but I am not sure if Excel allows this).

I currently have the code listed below, which is highlighting the cell yellow and turning the listed words red - but it matches occurrences within words.  How can I make it match only whole words?

```
    Sub ColorCertainWords()
      Dim Z As Long, Position As Long, Words As Variant, Cell As Range
      Words = Range("LIST") 'LIST defined by name manager as list of words that cannot be used
      For Each Cell In Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:AA6000") 'Range of cells to be checked
        If Len(Cell.Value) Then
            For Z = 1 To UBound(Words)
              Position = InStr(1, Cell.Value, Words(Z, 1), vbTextCompare)
              Do While Position
                Cell.Characters(Position, Len(Words(Z, 1))).Font.ColorIndex = 3  'Red
                Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 6 ' Yellow
                Position = InStr(Position + 1, Cell.Value, Words(Z, 1), vbTextCompare)
              Loop
            Next
        End If
      Next
      End Sub
```

Comment: Apparently `Position` marks the starting point of a found occurrence and `Len(Words(Z, 1))` indicates the length. So, you just have to make sure that the character before `Position` and after `Postion + Len(Words(Z, 1))`  are both a `(space)`. In short, by implementing an `If` clause which check both you can make sure that only complete occurrences are marked red.

Comment: Won't this cause issues if the word is at the beginning of the sentence, end of sentence, etc.? For example if I am looking for the word "dog" and the sentence in the cell is "Have you seen my dog?". This instance has dog followed by a "?" not a (space), which will create issues?

Comment: Then you will need to set up other checks for punctuation and if it is the first word or the last word.

Comment: My comment was only meant as a general *direction* in which you might want to start coding. We are not coding for you. We are only showing you the path and help you along the way (with bugs, errors, unwanted behavior, etc.). The above was posted as a comment and *not* as an answer. This is to get you going. Come back once you have expanded upon your current code (as pointed out by @ScottCraner).

Comment: I apologize if I projected that I was expecting you to code for me, I was looking for direction. Thank you.

Comment: I have become a pretty big fan of [regex](https://blog.udemy.com/vba-regex/) for things like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your modified code which will help you keep going.

```
Sub ColorCertainWords()
    Dim Z As Long, Position As Long, Words As Variant
    Dim Cell As Range, x As Integer, j As Integer
    Dim tempWords As Variant

    Words = Range("LIST")
    x = 1
    For Each Cell In Sheets("Sheet6").Range("A1:A6") 'Range of cells to be checked
        If Len(Cell.Value) Then
            tempWords = Split(Cell.Value, " ")  'Splitting cell value by space
            For i = LBound(tempWords) To UBound(tempWords)  'Looping through splitted values
                j = InStr(x, Cell.Value, " ") + 1
                For Z = 1 To UBound(Words)
                    If tempWords(i) = Words(Z, 1) Then  'Checking is words are matching
                        For k = 1 To Len(tempWords(i))
                            Cell.Characters(x, Len(tempWords(i))).Font.ColorIndex = 3  'Red
                            Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 6 ' Yellow
                        Next
                    End If
                Next
                x = j
            Next
            x = 1
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

And here is the test data with the resulted format that I've used:

[image]

Let me know if this will help.